# git status without checking out a branch

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-status

Say I have:

```
git fetch origin
git status "remotes/origin/master"
```

I am not sure if I can check the status of a branch that I haven't checked out, so let's say I checkout a branch like so:

```
git branch foo "remotes/origin/master"
git checkout foo
git status
```

my question is 2-fold:

1. Can I get the git status of a branch without checking it out?
2. Would the git status of foo ever be "unclean"? I would assume the git status of foo would always be "clean" and "up-to-date with the remote".

Comment: 1. `git remote show origin`? 2. Yes, if you have untracked files.

Comment: `git remote show origin` doesn't seem to include the same info as `git status`

Comment: True, it does not -- wasn't sure which of the info you needed -- but clearly any status information relative to your working tree isn't available from a remote. (Which is why `git status` _requires_ a local working tree.)

Answer (score 6):

> Can I get the git status of a branch without checking it out?

No, because `git status` shows the status of the working tree.  If you haven't checked out a branch, there is no working tree for it.

> Would the git status of foo ever be "unclean"?

It could be, if you have files which are not checked in (and not in `.gitignore`).   Those files would survive `git checkout <branch>`, and would appear as new files in any branch.

Comment: You can also compare the working copy to another branch by doing `git diff <branchname>`. That might be close to what OP is looking for.

Comment: `git diff` might be useful - what I am trying to do is see if a branch has changes when compared to the integration branch on the remote, which should be the same as `remotes/origin/integration`, if I do `git fetch origin`, right?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Then you'd want to `git fetch` and diff against `origin/integration`.